# OpenCV. Как получить координаты углов контура?

Tags: python, opencv

Дается случайное изображение с черным фоном и белым квадратом на нем. Нужно найти центр квадрата.

Есть такой код

```py
import cv2 as cv 
 
image = get_img() 
gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
 
contours, hierarchies, _ = cv.findContours(gray, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
 
centres = [] 
 
for i in contours: 
  moment = cv.moments(i) 
  if moment["m00"] != 0: 
    x = int(moment['m10']/moment['m00']) 
    y = int(moment['m01']/moment['m00']) 
  else: continue 
  centres.append(x) 
  centres.append(y) 
 
print(centres)
```

Впринципе он работает, но работает с готовыми изображениями. Проблема в том, что изображение генерируется через функцию `get_image()`. Допустим генерируется квадрат с центро: в точке `200 200`. Сейчас код начинает вести себя странно на этапе считывания моментов. Он находит кучу моментов `0` и `200`, соответственно `x` и `y` получаются равны `0` и `200` и так много раз.

Можно ли как-то упросить эту функцию или есть ли более надежная?
Я начал изучать openCV пару дней назад с надобностью и скорее всего неверно понял как работают моменты...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поиск чего-то в opencv работает не так как ожидатся. То есть зачастую возвращаются правильные результаты,- те на которые и рассчитывает разработчик. Но, так же часто возвращаются неверные результаты, которые к сожалению ни как нельзя проверить. Если суть задачи только в поиске белого квадрата, то проще напрямую работать с пикселями.

Answer (score 0):

Через threshold без перебора и без findContours

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]